# Mentor added his name as the author and changed the series of authors into alphabetical order, effectively putting my name at the last

Tags: publications, authorship, mentoring

I was recruited by a university to work on a research project as a research fellow and have dedicated over 8 months to it. I have maintained a schedule of fortnightly presentations with another senior research fellow and professor to update them with the progress of the research. After I shared the first draft of the paper with them, the senior fellow rewrote the introduction and added his and professor's name to the author list. He alphabetized the list by our last names stating that's the convention they are beginning t follow, which effectively puts my name at the very last. I have done all the research and I feel shortchanged. I did not like the fact that this was not even discussed with me before changing and the senior fellow will be presenting my paper, I was informed. Again, I am upset about this.

Yet, I have been in the system for 8 months, 4 more months to go before my contract is over with the institute. It matters a lot to me that my name appear first in the list of authors as I am planning to do my PhD soon and having a list of publications with my lead authorship will help me get work with the university of my choice.

What should I do? Should I let this go and not be bothered or should I discuss my concerns with the professor? The senior fellow and professor are very good friends and have been working together for over 6 years and I do not want them to gang up against me as I am new to the field. Please advise.,

Comment: What discipline?

Comment: I know of an IEEE Fellow who does exactly what you said.  His surname starts with B.  So he has many 'first' authored papers.

Comment: I think the key question is whether alphabetic author ordering is the standard convention in your field (in which case the seniors helped you learn the rules and conventions) or whether it is just something they like to do for their papers (which makes this a lot more tricky for you).

Comment: Immediately change your name from Allison Zymurgy to Allison Aardvark.

Comment: In fields that do not use the alphabetic order - such as biomedical sciences - the last position often indicates the most senior PI. So either your employers / applications committee will understand that the order is alphabetical, or assume that you were the PI, which is fine as well :)

Comment: In some countries it is the standard way. By the way, the last authors one is always spotted. Taking into account that the last one is usually the head of the lab, I guess the situation is easily recognised by colleagues and peers. If I would presented a paper like your, and being familiar to the field, I would conclude, with some guessing, that you were the main contributor. CV details will help further clarify that, as commented above.

Comment: @Alchimista Unless OP is already well-known in the field, how are readers supposed to assign any meaning to the alphabetical order? While the unknown other person doing most of the work (when the only other people are known to add themselves to every paper) is one option, another could be that the unknown person is some kind of research assistant who helped out a bit.

Comment: Depending on the rules within the community, you may want to add a footnote or a link explaining that you're listing authors in alphabetical order in the paper. I've seen quite often authors refer to this link (http://www.ams.org/profession/leaders/CultureStatement04.pdf) for math papers.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri Aad probably thought his name was enough. Until Aabout came to the ATLAS Collaboration.

Comment: @Llewellyn of course I can't draw something definitive from an alphabetical list. But in reality if a know x, y, and z, then I know what each did. Say W is unknown, then s/he did the most. Subtle cases may exist, like the presence of more than one student in the list. I also prefer listing in a more analytical way, at least for the ego of the young. I wanted to say that this practice won't damage the career.

Comment: @Alchimista How would you know what each contributor did just by knowing them? An individual wont always contribute the same amount to each paper they're an author on (their main project vs. helping someone else). How would you know that W isn't an intern? And besides, unless your field is extremely small, it's impossible to know everyone well enough to estimate their contribution.

Comment: @JSLavertu in practice it works like I am saying. Medicine and CERN are surely different. But there is not even such a discussion for paper with more than 4 5 authors. What one is looking for is who did the job and who is the boss. Other things I guess look important only to people not really in any fields.

Comment: @Alchimista I don't know what field you're in, but in mine it's not really possible to evaluate someone's contribution without the author ordering or a explicit mention. You could technically look at each author's publication history to get an idea of their expertise and estimate a contribution based on that, but considering the work required, I don't see any selection commitee doing so.

Comment: @JSLavertu but who is really looking for the difference between 2nd 3rd 4th author and so on? I really don't understand what you want to force here. Again, an order by contribution is what I prefer more. Or better, I did it years ago being a successful PhD student. An alphabetical order is not really detrimental.

Comment: @Alchimista The issue isn't 2nd, 3rd, and so on. It's first authorship. Some programs explicitely require a certain number of 1st author publications to graduate. For such a program, alphabetical order can quite literally ruin someone's career prospects.

Comment: I feel the answers to this question are mostly sort of weirdly missing the point. They're addressing "is it good for authors to be listed alphabetically in general?" That's a matter of opinion (at least, so far no answer is based on data), but obviously it depends on whether that's the norm within the field. This question seems to imply that it *isn't* the norm in the OP's field. This makes it a rather different question. It really seems to be about improper behaviour on the part of the OP's supervisor, and I'm surprised the answers are not focusing on helping the OP to deal with that.

Comment: I would point out the paper in question is "my" paper and I would do so in CV, presentation, hearings. When asked for paper in which I am first author, I would submit or present my work, citing with no rant the "convention" of the group. This is the most practical advice I can offer. This said, I would be disappointed as well if the alphabetical order would put in place right when my first paper got ready.

Answer (score 39):

Speaking from a field where author lists are always alphabetical: This will do you good in the long run! If you follow this convention, you will never have to argue over authorship order - take a look at the amount of questions on this site dealing with exactly this question, and be thrilled that you have the option to simply exclude that from your life.

Since I am in such a field, I also know what people do on their CV: they explain what they did for the study. You can write that you did the experiment, the analysis and wrote the first draft of the paper. This will be more informative for a hiring committee than any amount or author-list ordering principle you can come up with.

Comment: Doing so would be good for the field in general, but it's very likely to harm the OP's career. If their field doesn't order authors alphabetically/require first-author papers, their CV will take a massive hit. Making conventions more fair is definitively laudable, but its a bit unreasonable to ask OP to sacrifice their future for it... It's a bit of a catch-22.

Comment: @JSLavertu Makes no sense. Why would that prof have removed himself from the nice spot at the end of the list, if it wasn't the norm for the given journal, or the university had put up some new rule that forced him?

Comment: @Karl (Assuming OPs field orders names accordingly) the best spot is the first, not the last. If OPs name is last, their (apparent) contribution is minimized and will thus harm their CV. The professor's motives don't matter as far as OPs future career is concerned: they might be well intentioned, but unless the whole field switches at once, OP is penalized through no fault of their own.

Comment: @JSLavertu for senior people, the best spot is definitely the last, especially if students or more junior researchers are involved.

Comment: What @ZeroTheHero says. In such systems, the first spot is the person who did the actual work. The last spot is the person who provided guidance and direction. If an established professor appeared first in the author list, this would not be good at all. It would look very strange indeed. Did the professor himself actually stand at the lab bench day in, day out? Tape electrodes to subjects' skulls? Not good optics at all. (I am not discussing review papers and similar special circumstances. Which underlines why we can't really answer the question without more info.)

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I'm aware of that. Maybe the prof is at a point in their career where they no longer need to improve their CV and instead want to change the field's conventions. As I said, the prof's motivations (logical or not) don't matter as far as OPs career is concerned. (All assuming OP isn't in a field that organizes names alphabetically)

Comment: My name starts with W. I have been at the end of alphabetical lists all my life. At some point it will dawn on you that you _could_ game this system, it is possible to change your name, but you choose not to. There are also some advantages. You get longer to prepare for live presentations. It is also sometimes possible to insist on _reverse_ alphabetical listing to balance the systemic discrimination. If you are sparing and you use that phrasing finishing with that word in the right company, you have a political-correctness tactical nuclear weapon. But I like astronat's handling. It's tactful.

Comment: Indeed, I wish our area had the same convention rather than spending time to set the order.

Comment: Whether it will "do you good in the long run" depends to a measurable extent on the first letter of your surname. This has been studied and shown to have a significant effect on attaining tenure. There are also other measurable unintended effects of the system, including strongly discouraging people with names late in the alphabet from entering into collaborations with more than 2 other authors. See https://web.stanford.edu/~leinav/pubs/JEP2006.pdf

Comment: It should also go without saying that if alphabetic ordering is not the norm in the OP's field, then not putting the OP's name first will definitely significantly disadvantage them in both the short and the long term, since it's their first paper.

Answer (score 25):

In the first instance, I recommend talking to the professor and respectfully asking the reason why they changed the author ordering. However, unfortunately it is completely conventional in some fields to always list authors alphabetically, meaning that if your name is at the end of the alphabet you're unlikely to ever have a first author paper (note that if it *is* conventional in your field, the professors you apply to do your PhD with will also know this and hence not be surprised or worried by your lack of first authorship).

You can mitigate this somewhat when you list your publications in your CV. Consider writing a small description or footnote after the paper, saying that it was signed alphabetically and giving a brief explanation of your contribution. For example:

> **Publications**
>
> "Your paper title here", A. Aardvark, B. Bear, Y. Yourlastname<sup>1</sup>, *Journal of Things*, 2020.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>1</sup> Paper signed alphabetically. My contribution was completing X experiments, Y analysis and writing the first draft of the manuscript.

Comment: I would drop the word "unfortunately"; if alphabetical ordering *is* the convention, nobody makes any assumptions about your contribution to the paper based on your position in the list.

Comment: @chepner I suppose you could say "unfortunately" if it was a paper in an adjacent field where the OP's usual field is non-alphabetical.

Comment: Exactly; as a cosmologist I myself straddle this awkward boundary. Astronomers generally sign papers according to contribution, whereas our more theoretical colleagues (i.e. hep-th) tend to do it alphabetically. One's CV can look strange if you've collaborated with people from both sides of the fence.

Comment: @astronat and others, like you my spouse's research interests span fields with alphabetic and by-contribution authorship conventions. She (and others) have addressed the confused optics of this on their CV by underlining the lead author in each publication listed. (Bold seems to be semi-conventional for just making your own name visible in the list, so use -- and explain -- something else.)

Comment: @chepner Let's drop the "political correctness" here. It is **unfortunate** when the co-authors, most of the times your research advisors, do almost nothing yet shamelessly demand a spot in the authors list (and this is prevalent in academia) even if you did 100% of the work alone and funnily they will be the same defending the rationale behind alphabetical ordering, but won't acknowledge that they defend it only because it doesn't expose that their contribution is near to zero. It is also **unfortunate** when you want to work in industrial R&D and people there never see you as first author.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar experience a very long time ago: I was working with what would be my Ph.D. advisor's group and this work and I did a  long and involved calculation which was the major part of a paper. After I handed in the results and helped write up the paper I found out that my name was nowhere in the paper, and only got a thanks in the aknowledgement. I first went and found a new advisor on a different field. Next, I emailed the journal saying exactly the truth: that this was my work. I was next summoned by the head of the department, who on the one hand rightly chastized me for not coming to him first, but then held a hearing  commitee with 3 faculty members, to whom the former professor admitted that his contribution was basically 0 and my work was ingenious. The commitee forced them to put my name on the paper. It was the last author, but I had what I needed and had happily moved to an advisor more in tune with my ethics.

Comment: Non really pertinent but plus one for the happy end :)

Comment: It is very pertinent: The point is that because  of this behavior, right or wrong, relations are quite likely broken and as a result continuing to work with that group is likely to give rise to more issues. So, when the next paper comes along, do you wish to possibly go through the same issues with possibly the name put last or ommitted altogether?  SO have a plan B before severing ties. In fact if ties look irreparably destroyed, get a new plan A.

Comment: Being ignored as an author has little to do with the authors list. Say, if the OP group adopts the alphabetical order for real and for all papers, there is little to be offended of.

Answer (score 8):

As others have noted there are some fields (and subfields) where alphabetical ordering is the standard and everyone understands, expects, and respects that. A paper with a different ordering will stand out in some way.

But the solution in such a situation is to provide a short section in the paper itself, detailing the main contributions of each author. For the PI, it might just be providing the lab and guiding the research. For yourself it might say that you were the main driver of the research.

Such a section can come early in the paper or at the very end.

And, since you seem to imply that this professor, at least, is moving to an "alphabetical order" standard, it might be to head off such disputes in the future. But it would be hard for an individual, even a powerful one, to do this on their own. Usually it is the consensus of the majority of researchers in a field. Pure Math and Theoretical CS seem to have such a standard.

Some lab sciences do not. Especially those in which a paper could possibly have hundreds of "co-authors".

---

Let me add a bit about fairness. Yes, you can ask the professor for the reasoning, but it might be a mistake to try to argue the case, because of the power imbalance if nothing else.

But, if there are unequal contributions that can be clearly identified, then fairness suggests that they be recognized *somehow*, even if not in author order. Hence, the suggestion of a contributions section.

But it is a bit subtle. Sometimes people contribute to a bit of research in different enough, but essential, ways so that any notion of "priority" is meaningless. Other times it is clear. In mathematics, for example, it can be devilishly difficult to work out priority when people are contributing insights into a problem. A person who spends little time on a problem might just provide the key insight that makes the solution possible.

In some fields there is a clear "driver" of the intellectual content of a piece of research and other contribute, perhaps with a lot of time and effort, but the *ideas* and insights come from on person or a small group. There it is a bit clearer how priority is assigned and it should be recognized.

In your particular case, you may be able to argue for that recognition in a way that everyone is comfortable with.

Comment: I've never seen such a statement early in the paper. It has always been at the end for the journals I've submitted to.

Comment: @WetlabStudent I've seen it in a footnote on the first page sometimes. More broadly, it's worth pointing out that such a section or footnote will not be visible on a list of publications and won't be accounted for in any bibliometrics - if alphabetical ordering is not the norm in the OP's field then such a section wouldn't really be a good compromise - they should just be listed first.

Answer (score 5):

**Ask the group if you can be the "corresponding author"**

In most disciplines, the corresponding author is either the lead author who did most of the writing/work or the PI on the project. They handle the submission and are in direct contact with the journal. If you are marked as the corresponding author on the publication, it will be assumed that you were a major contributor to the work, even if your position in the author list is close to the back. This convention generally holds more across fields than author order - for example some applied math journals have alphabetical author lists, but they still mark a corresponding author.

Note at the end of the paper you can put a section called "Author contributions" where you summarise what everyone did. Many journals require such a statement. For journals that don't require such a statement, I have never had a journal ask I remove it [mostly general science, applied math, biology, and environmental science journals].

On a CV you can put an asterisk in front of all papers where you are the lead/corresponding author. And explain this at the top of your publication list.

Comment: 100% agree. 
This should be marked in the paper with a footnote or a remark next to your affiliation (or by the fact that only your email address is present)

Comment: This is also pretty field dependent I think. I've heard there are some fields where the "corresponding author" is understood to be the one who made the biggest contribution, but there are others where it means nothing more than the person who uploaded the paper to the journal's submission system.

Comment: @Nathaniel very rarely would a minor author be the one to upload the paper and handle all correspondence with the journal's submission system (I've never seen this before in my entire career across 5 universities and 3 disciplines, one of which goes by alphabetical order). This is even true in fields where the corresponding author is not guaranteed to be the head of the lab or the person who did the most work. In such fields its merely a piece of evidence that will be suggestive that you were a major contributor to the work, if anyone ever questions it.

Comment: Fair enough. I just think that being able to provide suggestive evidence if someone asks isn't really what the OP should be aiming for. If the OP's field doesn't list authors alphabetically then the OP should be first author, and it's absolutely improper for their senior colleague to change that. Being corresponding author just won't have the same impact on a CV that being first author would. (On the other hand, if authors *are* usually listed alphabetically in the OP's field then your suggestion is a very reasonable one - we unfortunately don't know that.)

Comment: @Nathaniel agreed. This is mainly if the field is alphabetical or the PI has refused to switch the author order back and other amicable actions have failed.

Answer (score 2):

- Please check if the journal actually has a detailing section of the contributions  (i think in nature or science this was in the end of the paper)
- Check the Rules of the Journal, could be that they ask for alphabetical order

Answer (score 2):

This is very field dependent, and also can depend a lot on sub-fields within a field. I don't know what your (sub)field is, but since you say the justification is that "that's the convention they are beginning to follow", I am guessing it is not universal in your sub-field.

If that is the case then you are right to be upset. This will harm you as a young researcher, while only marginally benefitting the more senior people who have been shuffled to the front. You are also right to be upset that this was not discussed with you.

In this situation, I would send a reply to both the senior fellow and the professor, stating politely but very clearly that this wasn't discussed with you, and that you are not happy with it, giving exactly the reasons you gave in your SE post. It's quite likely that they haven't really thought about it from your point of view, and the professor may or may not be unaware that it hasn't been discussed with you. In that case I would expect that such a mail would result in a swift change.

It's important to be polite, so as not to be seen as being difficult about it, but this is a situation where you do have every right to make your view known. If the  authors aren't usually listed alphabetically in your field then you absolutely should be the first author.

Comment: I'm a bit less sure about this point, so I didn't include it in my answer, but I think generally the fields where authors are listed alphabetically are ones where the barrier to being an author is very high. In maths, for example, it would not be acceptable to add a professor's name to a paper if they didn't actively contribute to the main ideas of the work. In fields where authors can make only minor contributions the order of authors tends to be used to indicate this - if they were listed alphabetically nobody would know who actually did the work.

Answer (score 1):

**Name change (Yes seriously)**

My immediate thought was a name-change. I see that this has already been suggested (perhaps jokingly) in a comment  @A. I. Breveleri

---

**Personal anecdote**

Some years ago I changed my surname (by [deed poll](https://www.gov.uk/change-name-deed-poll) - I live in Britain). My original surname was "Smith". I wasn't ashamed of this but got fed up with people complaining they couldn't find me in company lists. I changed my name to something distinctive that I liked - I wasn't worried about alphabetical order. It is remarkable how people react differently to you when they hear a cool sounding surname! People even perceive me as more intelligent now! (Hint: Look up [nominative determinism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_determinism) - it doesn't just work on oneself).

Because my surname is unusual now - I share it with a famous film actor - people remember me.

---

**But it's too late for this paper!**

Your name seems to indicate that you are female. Just tell them that you are engaged to be married and that you want to change your name ahead of time in order to have consistency with your future publications. Get a friend to pose as John Aardvark. Aardvark is perhaps a little extreme and people will cotton on, however there are plenty of "A" names out there. Personally I would go for it - academics will love or hate you for it but you can bet they will remember you!

If making the change immediately would arouse suspicions, you could change your name after publication and see it as a future investment. If you have the necessary aplomb though, there isn't much they can do.

**Long term**

Having a memorable (not to say exceptional and cool-sounding name) will be a good career move on its own merit. Having a cool name that is also early in the alphabet will double your credibility - it will be the first thing that people see. So would having a name starting with "Z" by the way. You might like to consider this - it would arouse less suspicion. The effectiveness of always being at the and of a list relates to the well-established [Serial Position Effect](https://www.simplypsychology.org/primacy-recency.html).

---

Incidentally, I'll bet that, with the new alphabetic trend, and the acceptability of pseudonyms in academic publications, people will all start doing this and eventually papers will be written by authors all beginning with "A". It's called the [law of unintended consequences](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2020/09/01/one-ironclad-rule-history-law-unintended-consequences/).

Comment: Changing your name is completely overkill for this situation. If OPs field is alphabetically sorted, changing their name will accomplish nothing. If it is, the issue is with the supervisor, not with OPs name.

Comment: I disagree that it will accomplish nothing. If you read the question carefully, the OP's major concern is about appearing first in the list of authors. In this situation, changing one's name prior to submission of a paper *will* change the order in which authors are credited.  No amount of complaining or  pleading will get anyone to change the "industry standard" for the benefit of one person.

Comment: P.S.  Of course the whole thing is a dirty trick. I had something similar happen to me once - I actually suggested the topic of some software and did *all* the work, merely presenting the finished result to my then manager.  It became a product and the manager's name appeared in huge letters, my name was in small print.  It teed me off at the time but had no long-term affect on my career.

Comment: Unless OP specifies their field, we have no way of knowing if it's the industry standard or not. It will accomplish nothing in the sense that being first in a field that sorts names alphabetically is irrelevant. OP would gain nothing by changing their name. Changing your name has two main advantages: Less confusion (as in your case), and bypassing the professor's intent to disregard a non-alphabetical standard.

Comment: *"bypassing the professor's intent "* Exactly. If the professor then changes the rules about who comes first once more, it shows his hypocrisy. Either way it is likely to P him off and cause bad feeling. But then the OP is already feeling bad. However, I am naturally a risk-taker. This approach will not suit everyone.  That's why I suggested writing it off to experience and strategically changing name afterwards.  Or, of course just accept the situation and rely on gaining a reputation for good research under one's own name  regardless of its alphabetic placement.

Comment: We'll have to agree to disagree. IMO, the prof's behavior is the problem. The solution is to adress the behavior directly, not to game around it with drastic decisions like changing your name (all assuming OP is in a non-alphabetical field).

Comment: No problem. I agree to disagree. :-)